# How to establish secondary NSSortDescriptor sort key?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode4.2, nssortdescriptor

I have successfully sorted the data I have by my sort key `lastName`, but I want to know how to sort by `lastName`, and then by `firstName`.  Here is the code I used to sort by `lastName`

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"firstName" ascending:YES];
[request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
```

How do I add the secondary sort key of `firstName`?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"firstName" ascending:YES];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor2 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"lastName" ascending:YES];

[request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor1, sortDescriptor2, nil]];
```

Comment: The solution is gone @tarheel. The link is dead.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that you are passing an array of sort descriptors. Simply create another descriptor for firstname and create the array with both descriptors. They will be applied in the order of the array.